# Find duplicate values, group that values then make a sum of the values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array and i try to group  and sum the valorDolar but i can't

so, in my code i run the array inside the array for que the equal data and group that.

My Code

```
    foreach ($array_DocumentOne as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($array_DocumentOne as $k => $v) {
            if ($key < $k && $value['fraccion'] == $v['fraccion']) {

                $sum = $value['valorDolar'] + $v['valorDolar'];

                $duplicateInDocOne[] = array(
                    $value,
                    $v,
                    $sum
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

that code run into the same array to find duplicate Fraccion and make the group of the Fraccion and make the sum for all the valorDolar found

```
[data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                  [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 12000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 16.32
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 175.20
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 5
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 5000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 13.125
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "tex"
                                [valorDolar] => 388.10
                            )

                        [2] => 563.3
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 12000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 16.32
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 175.20
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 6
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 2000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 0.62
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 169.08
                            )

                        [2] => 344.28
                    )
```

i want to see an array like this

```
[data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                  [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 12000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 16.32
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 175.20
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 5
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 5000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 13.125
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "tex"
                                [valorDolar] => 388.10
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 12000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 16.32
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 175.20
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 6
                                [fraccion] => 39232101
                                [SUBD] => 
                                [vinc] => 0
                                [met_val] => 6
                                [umc] => 6
                                [cantidad_umc] => 2000
                                [umt] => 1
                                [cantidad_umt] => 0.62
                                [pvc] => MEX
                                [pod] => MEX
                                [Descripcion] => "text"
                                [valorDolar] => 169.08
                            )

                        [4]=> 907.58
                    )
```

Comment: and what have you tried to get it? can you please share the code you using?

Comment: So, what have you tried? We're glad to help you sort out issues with your code, but you need to at least have tried something. SO is not a free coding service. If you have tried something, post that code and we might be able to help. If you haven't, please do that before asking. Also, you need to explain the expected results. How are they grouped? What are the criteria/rules?

Comment: ready i attach the code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but I give it a try...

**I put in some data for testing:**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [valorDolar] => 100
                                [fraccion] => 15453
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 2
                                [valorDolar] => 200
                                [fraccion] => 16453
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 3
                                [valorDolar] => 400
                                [fraccion] => 15453
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [sec] => 3
                                [valorDolar] => 600
                                [fraccion] => 16453
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

If I understand you correctly you would like to group by fraccion.
```

You can use the fact that you can store any index as a key in an array in PHP:

```
    $group_arr = array();
    foreach ($array_DocumentOne as $outer_key => $outer_array) {
        foreach ( $outer_array as $inner_key => $inner_array) {
            foreach ( $inner_array as $item_key => $array_item) {
                $groupby_item = $array_item['fraccion'];
                $group_arr[$groupby_item][] = $array_item;
            }
        }
     }
```

and you will get an array (`$group_arr`) like this:

```
Array
(
    [15453] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 2
                    [valorDolar] => 100
                    [fraccion] => 15453
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 3
                    [valorDolar] => 400
                    [fraccion] => 15453
                )

        )

    [16453] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 2
                    [valorDolar] => 200
                    [fraccion] => 16453
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sec] => 3
                    [valorDolar] => 600
                    [fraccion] => 16453
                )

        )

)
```

...which you can use to sum up the values for each group.